# How do I solve Error retrieving component IndexedVar[1]: The component has not been constructed

Tags: pyomo

I'm getting this error (Error retrieving component IndexedVar[1]: The component has not been constructed.), and I can't figure out where I went wrong with my code below, I'm coding a linear program in pyomo, I'm not versed in python, I'm basically repeating when I learned for linear programming. Can you help me out? The error seems to be in the line defining the objective function... please help

'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Sun Jun 12 20:01:39 2022

@author: israathiab
"""

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

def pyomoresults(QEMCAProfitModel): # define a function to print optimization results
""""Print results of the optimization of model 'QEMCAProfitModel' including 
objective value at optimum, optimal decision variable values and 
dual/slack information on constraints"""
print('')
print('=========================')
print('QEMCAProfitModel Maximization Solution')
print('=========================')
print('')
print('Objective Function Value at Optimum')
# loop over objective objects in the model
for f in QEMCAProfitModel.component_objects(pyo.Objective, active=True):
    print ('Objective', f) # print the name of the objective
    # loop over subobjectives (in this course we will only have one)
    for index in f: 
        print ('      ', index, pyo.value(f[index]))
print('')
print('Decision Variable Values at Optimum')
# loop over decision variable objects in model
for v in QEMCAProfitModel.component_objects(pyo.Var, active=True):
    print ('Variable', v) # print variable name
    for index in v: # loop over index of variable object
        # print index/optimal values
        print ('      ', index, pyo.value(v[index])) 
print('')
print ('Duals/Shadow Prices at Optimum')
# loop over constraint objects in model
for d in QEMCAProfitModel.component_objects(pyo.Constraint, active=True):
    print ('Constraint',d) # print constraint name
    for index in d: # loop over index of constraint object
        # print dual value of constraint
        print ('      ', index, QEMCAProfitModel.dual[d[index]]) 
print('')     
print ("Slack at Optimum")
# loop over constraint objects in model
for i in QEMCAProfitModel.component_objects(pyo.Constraint, active=True):
    print ("   Constraint",Ci) # print constraint name
    for index in Ci: # loop over index of constraint object
        # print constraint slack information
        print ("      ", index, Ci[index].lslack(), ' - ', Ci[index].uslack()) 


#Define Concrete model

QEMCAProfitModel = pyo.ConcreteModel

#Define variable dictionary for decision variable index 

#Crop index

I = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

#Define parameters

#Define mean profit per crop - ETB

mPi = {1:15635.2, 2:9571.36, 3:13392.6, 4:39834.6, 5:49074.1, 6:11365.6}

#Define mean cost per hectar of crop - ETB/Hecatre

Ci = {1:10467.37, 2:8160.47, 3:12392.22, 4:5702.01, 5:8265.88, 6:8514.31}

#Define objective function

QEMCAProfitModel.L = pyo.Var(I,within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)



QEMCAProfitModel.Profit = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(mPi[i] * QEMCAProfitModel.L[i] for i `in I), sense=pyo.maximize)`
#Profit un EBT

#Define constraints

def Budget_rule(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return sum(Ci[i] * QEMCAProfitModel.L[i] for i in I) <= 850636 
QEMCAProfitModel.Budget_rule = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Budget_rule)


def Land_rule(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return sum(QEMCAProfitModel.L[i] for i in I) <= 47.77  
QEMCAProfitModel.Land_rule = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Land_rule)

def Land_rule_min(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return sum(QEMCAProfitModel.L[i] for i in I) >= 0  
QEMCAProfitModel.Land_rule_min = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Land_rule_min)


def Consumption_rule_1(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 4560.64 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[1] >= 51250
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_1 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_1)

def Consumption_rule_2(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 5764.71 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[2] >= 36710
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_2 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_2)


def Consumption_rule_3(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 9908.3 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[3] >= 30316
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_3 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_3)


def Consumption_rule_4(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 16614.81 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[4] >= 4850
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_4 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_4)

def Consumption_rule_5(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 20323.81 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[5] >= 4450
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_5 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_5)

def Consumption_rule_6(QEMCAProfitModel, i):
return 4400 * QEMCAProfitModel.L[6] >= 7100
QEMCAProfitModel.Consumption_rule_6 = pyo.Constraint(I, rule=Consumption_rule_6)

QEMCAProfitModel.pprint()

QEMCAProfitModel.dual = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT)

opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')

results = opt.solve(QEMCAProfitModel)

QEMCAProfitModel.display()

QEMCAProfitModel.dual.display()

pyomoresults(QEMCAProfitModel)

'''
```

Comment: I do not see the IndexedVar variable in your model. Does the error mention exactly that or is it related to the "L" variable that you have in your mathematical model?

Comment: I think it's in relation to variable "L". below is the full text of the error I get

runfile('/Users/israathiab/Downloads/QE MCA Scenario 1.py', wdir='/Users/israathiab/Downloads')
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: File "/Users/israathiab/Downloads/QE MCA Scenario 1.py", line 71, in <module>
    QEMCAProfitModel.Profit = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(QEMCAProfitModel.X[i] * mPi[i] for i in I), sense = pyo.maximize)

  File "/Users/israathiab/Downloads/QE MCA Scenario 1.py", line 71, in <genexpr>
    QEMCAProfitModel.Profit = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(QEMCAProfitModel.X[i] * mPi[i] for i in I), sense = pyo.maximize)File "/Users/israathiab/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component.py", line 365, in __getitem__
    self._not_constructed_error(index)

Comment: File "/Users/israathiab/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component.py", line 509, in _not_constructed_error
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error retrieving component IndexedVar[1]: The component has not been constructed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parens when defining the model object:

```
QEMCAProfitModel = pyo.ConcreteModel
```

should be

```
QEMCAProfitModel = pyo.ConcreteModel()
```

Without the parens, `QEMCAProfitModel` is the *class* `ConcreteModel` instead of an instance of the class.  The "magic" that triggers component "construction" (the `__setattr__` method on Block data instances) only works on `Block` instances (and a model is a block).

Note that the same method is also responsible for copying the attribute name to the component name.  Since that is not being triggered, you are seeing the default component name (the class name, `IndexedVar`) in the error message.